# Fire jquery event once

Tags: jquery

So this fires each time the user scrolls the page to load in more posts.

It uses

```
$("#next-paginav")[0].click();
```

because it's an anchor it's 'clicking' on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function (e) { 

        var intBottomMargin = 300; 


        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('main-content').height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {


             setTimeout(function(){ $("#next-paginav")[0].click(); }, 800);
        }

    });
});
```

Dipesh's code that I can't get to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function (e) { 

        var intBottomMargin = 300; 


        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('main-content').height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {


             setTimeout(function(){ 
             $("#next-paginav")[0].one('click',function() {  });

              }, 800);


        }

    });
});
```

The problem is that it fires so quickly it fires two, three, four times before the posts even load in.
This causes all sorts of problems, aside from the fact it'd be making so many requests on a live server, sometimes it skips over posts.
Is there a way to only fire it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout = '';
    $(window).scroll(function (e) { 
        var intBottomMargin = 300; 
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('main-content').height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {
          timeout = setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("#next-paginav")[0].click(); 
          }, 800);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, this doesn't seem to want to work in firefox on OS X, where you don't get the 'bounce' at the bottom of the page like in Chrome.
It does however work when I take the height:100% off the html element.
How would I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.one()` jQuery handler..

> **Description:** Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

**[`Official Document`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**

**Example**

```
$("#next-paginav")[0].one('click',function() {  });
```

You can also use `.off()` handler too.

**Example**

```
$("#next-paginav")[0].click(function(){
  $(this).off(event);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work.
setTimeout(function(){ $("#next-paginav")[0].one('click',function(); }, 800);

Comment: @andy what exactly you need.??? click event once..?? if yes then above code work...if you want to trigger click event then use `.trigger` jQuery handler.

Comment: I want it to fire once, your code gives me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'one'"

This:- $("#next-paginav")[0].one('click',function() {  }); doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
    $("#next-paginav")[0].one('click',function (e) {
```

or you can try with "live"

```
    $("#next-paginav")[0].live('click',function (e) {
```

as per the "live" method is deprecated as from jquer1.7 You can use "on" method like

```
    $("#next-paginav")[0].on('click',function (e) {
```

Comment: you can replace live with 'on' method. live is deprecated. btw i dint downvote

Comment: Yah I have mentioned that now

Comment: @GautamD3164 The problem with this is I don't see how to integrate it.

setTimeout(function(){ $("#next-paginav")[0].click(); }, 800);

How do I put this in there? $("#next-paginav")[0].one('click',function (e) {

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is if there is already a schedules load then you do not want to trigger the loading again.

You can use a flag based solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var intBottomMargin = 300;

    $(document).scroll(function(e) {
        if (clickFlag) {
            return;
        }

        clickFlag = true;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('main-content').height()
                - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {

            setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#next-paginav")[0].click();
                    }, 800);
        }

    });
});

var clickFlag = false;
function myClickHandler() {
    $.ajax({}).always(function() {
                clickFlag = false;
            })
}
```

Comment: That works the first time, but only loads the first set of posts then doesn't load anymore.

Comment: can you share the on click handler

Comment: Uh, I don't know what that is.